# MySQL connection from command line, how can be a command line utility so unstable?

Tags: mysql

Since a few hours I'm trying to connect to a local sql environment. It works in one second with MySQL Workbench, but from the commandline MySQL is not very verbose :)

```
mysql -u root -p root --host=127.0.0.1 --port=10011 -password'root'
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

1. Somewhere they report to use -u, while somewhere else they suggest --u
2. How do I find out if mysql is able to reach the server?
3. What else can I do for troubleshooting?

[image]

Comment: It's either `-h` or `--host`. The other combinations you're trying out don't make sense. What are the exact credentials you're using from Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL command line is a mess, the solution was

mysql -**u**root -**h**127.0.0.1 --port=10011 -**p**root

Some with -- like port and some with - like p, and with no space.

Comment: You can see possible arguments with `mysql --help` or [online](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html). User can be set with `--user=user_name` or `-u user_name`, host with `--host=host_name` or `-h host_name`, port with `--port=port_num` or `-P port_num` (note the uppercase P) and password with `--password[=password]` or `-p[password]` (you shouldn't type brackets, they just mean it's optional).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález so if I use the long variant I need -- and =